# find all with aggregate in mongodb with another key in that object array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate

I have collection like this,

1. **company** has many **people**
2. **person** has many **companies**

the company document like this :

```
{
         "_id" : ObjectId("5eeecf60a3a0d434693efe9a"),
        "name" : "ONE",
        "members" : []
}

{
         "_id" : ObjectId("5eeec400d655e7af27b07d8a"),
        "name" : "Two TWO",
        "members" : [ 
                      {"_id": ObjectId("5eeec400d65ddddd5555"), "status": false}
                    ]
}
```

This is what I tried using `aggregation`

```
db.companies.aggregate(
                    {
                     "$lookup": {
                        "from": "people", 
                        "localField": "members._id",
                        "foreignField": "_id", 
                        "as": "members"}
                     }).pretty()
```

After aggregation, the `status` is missing from the resulting objects.

Here's the aggregation result.

```
{
         "_id" : ObjectId("5eeec400d655e7af27b07d8a"),
        "name" : "Two TWO",
        "members" : [
                      {
                        "_id": ObjectId("5eeec400d65ddddd5555"),
                        "name": "John DO"
                        "gender": "male"
                      }
                    ]
}
{
         "_id" : ObjectId("5eeecf60a3a0d434693efe9a"),
        "name" : "ONE",
        "members" : []
}
```

Is it possible to include `status` key as a part of aggregation output
**Expected Output**

```
members : [
      {
        company: {
                    "_id": ObjectId("5eeec400d65ddddd5555"),
                    "name": "John DO"
                    "gender": "male"
                 }
        status: false
      }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In lookup, you are storing it **as** `matching document` result in `members`.

This is replacing your existing `members` object from your `$$ROOT`

To maintain the original `$members` from `companies` as well as `$members` from people.

You would need to `merge` both objects in `$project` phase.

Here's a breakdown of pipeline:

**Phase 1**: `$unwind` on `$members` to to pull members array at $ROOT level.

**Phase2**: `$lookup` document from `people` collection and store it under `fromPeople` attribute.

**Phase 3**: Assuming you have only one matching document fromPeople, merge object element at array index 0, with `$ROOT.members`, store the merged object in `members` attribute.

```js
db.companies.aggregate([
    {
      $unwind:{path: "$members"} 
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "people", 
            "localField": "members._id",
            "foreignField": "_id", 
            "as": "fromPeople"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            members: { $mergeObjects: [ { $arrayElemAt: [ "$fromPeople", 0 ] }, "$$ROOT.members" ] },
        }
    }
])
```

**Output**

```
{
    "_id" : "5eeec400d655e7af27b07d8a",
    "members" : {
        "_id" : "5eeec400d65ddddd5555",
        "name" : "John DO",
        "gender" : "male",
        "status" : false
    }
}
```

Comment: is that mean the company who has no member will now show off here ??

Comment: if `members` array is empty from the company it won't show up in unwind